# help with editing shapefile

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile

I am not sure how this is done but I Have a shapefile with state borders for a country. What I would like is to sort of delete/dissolve the state borders and be left with only the country border.   In the data attribute table, there are only polygons for the states and none for the country.
How is this done in Arcinfo or Global Mapper 10?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track, the command is actually called "Dissolve". It's in ArcToolbox, under Data Management > Generalization. Run it, choose your state borders as the input layer, specify an output layer, and click OK. If you want to dissolve an entire polygon shapefile into one large polygon, you don't need to worry about the other parameters.

Comment: OK.. I have tried it and this is the problem I run into. My data is 50 states polygon and NO country polygon all in one shapefile.  So when I dissolve I am pretty much choosing the name or id of the 50 states and when it is done.  I still have the map with the states but in the table: only thing left is the id and polygon( no names or other info). So that is not really working. What am I missing

Comment: What Dan means by ignoring the other parameters is that you can leave all of the possible Dissolve fields unchecked (instead of choosing one of your available state attributes).  Simply enter your output feature name, make sure all dissolve fields are unchecked and select OK.